# how can i extract a result from array in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
window.onload = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/auctionCount.kh",
        data:{memberNo:memberNo},
        success : function(list){
            for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                console.log(list[i]);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

[image]

I got it as a hashmap type in sql.

I need to extract divno, prevcount, projectname, projectno, viewdif, viewcount separately here but I don't know how

Comment: *"extract a result"*? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you simply wish to access them, you'd just use the dot operator:

```
console.log(list[i].DIVNO);
console.log(list[i].VIEWDIF);
// etc..
```

If you want to access the objects key-value pairs, regardless of what they are:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(list[i])) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you like one liner you can do it like this

```js
let data = [{DIVNO: 4, PREVCOUNT: 5, PROJECTNAME: 'xx', PROJECTNO: 21, VIEWCOUNT: 0, VIEWDIF: 0}, {DIVNO: 5, PREVCOUNT: 6, PROJECTNAME: 'xx2', PROJECTNO: 22, VIEWCOUNT: 1, VIEWDIF: 1}];


const result = data.reduce((res, item) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(item).map(([k, v]) => [k, [...(res[k] || []), v]])
), {})

console.log(result);
```